# Sonic Annotator set VAMP Plugin Folder Location

Tags: sonic

I would like to have the Vamp Plugins folder in the same folder as Sonic Annotator rather than the default locations below.
How do I specify this for command line use ?

```
Linux:   /usr/local/lib/vamp
OS/X:    /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Vamp
Windows: C:\Program Files\Vamp Plugins
Solaris: /usr/local/lib/vamp
```

Answer (score 1):

Linux and macOS using bash in a terminal window:

$ export VAMP_PATH=/path/to/plugin/directory

$ sonic-annotator -l

(or whatever sonic-annotator options you want)

Windows using Command Prompt:

set VAMP_PATH=/path/to/plugin/directory

sonic-annotator -l

Windows using PowerShell:

$env:VAMP_PATH = "/path/to/plugin/directory"

& sonic-annotator -l

Note that in all cases, setting the path to "." will make Sonic Annotator read plugins from the current working directory at the time you run it. If you have plugins + sonic-annotator binary in the same directory, you can cd to that directory and run (in bash) the one-liner

$ VAMP_PATH=. ./sonic-annotator -l